# Scala/Spark - Find total number of value in row based on a key

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a large text file which contains the page views of some Wikimedia projects. (You can find it [here](https://dumps.wikimedia.org/other/pagecounts-raw/2016/2016-01/pagecounts-20160101-000000.gz) if you're really interested) Each line, delimited by a space, contains the statistics for one Wikimedia page. The schema looks as follows:
`<project code> <page title> <num hits> <page size>`

In Scala, using Spark RDDs or Dataframes, I wish to compute the total number of hits for each project, based on the project code.
So for example for projects with the code "zw", I would like to find all the rows that begin with project code "zw", and add up their hits. Obviously this should be done for all project codes simultaneously.

I have looked at functions like aggregateByKey etc, but the examples I found don't go into enough detail, especially for a file with 4 fields. I imagine it's some kind of MapReduce job, but how exactly to implement it is beyond me.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do `GroupBy` to the DataFrame. Try it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you have to read the file in as a `Dataset[String]`. Then, parse each string into a tuple, so that it can be easily converted to a `Dataframe`. Once you have a `Dataframe`, a simple `.GroupBy().agg()` is enough to finish the computation.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.sum

val df = spark.read.textFile("/tmp/pagecounts.gz").map(l => {
    val a = l.split(" ")
    (a(0), a(2).toLong)
}).toDF("project_code", "num_hits")

val agg_df = df.groupBy("project_code")
  .agg(sum("num_hits").as("total_hits"))
  .orderBy($"total_hits".desc)

agg_df.show(10)
```

The above snippet shows the top 10 project codes by total hits.

```
+------------+----------+
|project_code|total_hits|
+------------+----------+
|       en.mw|   5466346|
|          en|   5310694|
|       es.mw|    695531|
|       ja.mw|    611443|
|       de.mw|    572119|
|       fr.mw|    536978|
|       ru.mw|    466742|
|          ru|    463437|
|          es|    400632|
|       it.mw|    400297|
+------------+----------+
```

It is certainly also possible to do this with the older API as an `RDD` map/reduce, but you lose many of the optimizations that `Dataset`/`Dataframe` api brings.